# Check and update the row depending on same or different value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update the status if all the rows value is set to same value.

my query like this

```
$ord = "SELECT * FROM plitems WHERE pur_order_id='".$order_id."'";
    $ord1 = mysqli_query($con, $ord);

    while($ord2 = mysqli_fetch_array($ord1)) {

        if(($ord2['invoice_status']=='Invoiced')) 
        {
            $m5 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE pur_orders SET status='Invoiced' WHERE pur_order_id='".$order_id."'");

        }
        else
        {
            $m5 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE pur_orders SET status='Partial' WHERE pur_order_id='".$order_id."'");

        }
```

But here i have 2 line items in `plitems` table, 1st line item status is `Invoiced` and 2nd line item status is `Partial`, But still it is setting `pur_orders` status as Invoiced instead of `Partial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a query that uses `GROUP BY` to find the orders that have all the same status.

```
UPDATE pur_orders AS p
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(invoice_status) AS invoice_status
      FROM plitems
      WHERE pur_order_id = $order_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT invoice_status) = 1) AS t
SET p.status = t.invoice_status
WHERE p.pur_order_id = $order_id
```

If there's just one status, the subquery will return one row with that status, and it will then be assigned to `pur_orders.status`. If there's more than one status, the subquery will return no rows, so the `CROSS JOIN` will produce an empty cross product, and it won't update anything.

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/YRYT29403)

Comment: what is `t.status` here? it says unknown column

Comment: Sorry should be `t.invoice_status`

Comment: No Sir, Still is is updating `pur_order.status='Invoiced' `

Comment: Shouldn't have had `GROUP BY invoice_status`. Now it works.